# how do I trigger an existing jquery function with a form select option

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have a working jQuery function which uses .click(function to simultaneously fill multiple input text fields with data from hidden div elements on the same page. It was fine with just a few fields but now it has expanded and there is clutter.

I figure I can reduce the clutter by using a form select dropdown to trigger the existing function and hide the current buttons but I do not know how to achieve that, so I seek assistance.

This is my code. The dropdown selection does nothing. Just there to show my concept.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#cardformats li').click(function () {
  var curRowId = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#cardhead').val( $('#' + curRowId + ' div.cardhead').text() );
  $('#cardbody').val( $('#' + curRowId + ' div.cardbody').text() );
  $('#cardfoot').val( $('#' + curRowId + ' div.cardfoot').text() );
 });
 });


<form>
<select id="grabber" name="grab">
    <option value="card1">Card Format 1</option>
    <option value="card2">Card Format 2</option>
    <option value="card3">Card Format 3</option>
</select>
    <ul id="cardformats">
        <li id="row1">Card Format 1
            <div class="cardhead">Busines Name</div>
            <div class="cardbody">Address</div>
            <div class="cardfoot">Phone and Name</div>
        </li>
        <li id="row2">Card Format 2
            <div class="cardhead">Address and Phone</div>
            <div class="cardbody">Business Name</div>
            <div class="cardfoot">Name and Website</div>
        </li>
        <li id="row3">Card Format 3
            <div class="cardhead">Name</div>
             <div class="cardbody">Busines Name</div>
            <div class="cardfoot">Website and Phone</div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="inputs">
        <li><label>Card Head</label>
            <input size="50" id="cardhead" type="text"></li>
        <li><label>Card Body</label>
             <input size="50" id="cardbody" type="text"></li>
        <li><label>Card Foot</label>
            <input size="50" id="cardfoot" type="text"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

this is your solution with minimum changes in your existing code.

1. I changed `li` id with `value` of `dropdown`
2. Written change handler on dropdown

**Note:** there may be optimised solutions available for your case

write change handler on select box :

```
  $("#grabber").change(function(){
     //code
    });
```

demo link:  http://jsfiddle.net/BuxsF/

Comment: This solution works perfectly, thanks. I am certainly interested in any solution that would optimize my coding.

Comment: yes it can be only done by you...by analyzing your scenario. e.g if div values under each li is static,then you can put those in array and load that accordingly..